# Pinch-zooming img in html 5 without zooming other markers

Tags: html, css

Hi I have problem with pinch-zooming. I have web-applications (presentations) and I would like to be able to zoom in/zoom out using pinch on touch screen monitor. When I doing pinch whole browser becoming bigger or smaller, but I would like make it only on img.

How to achieve  it? Any ideas?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any code, so I can only provide you some general guidance. Listen for the `gestureend` event, and read the `scale` property of the `GestureEvent` that gets passed in':

> scale: 
>   The distance between two fingers since the start of an event, as a multiplier of the initial distance.
>
> The initial value is 1.0. If less than 1.0, the gesture is pinch close (to zoom out). If greater than 1.0, the gesture is pinch open (to zoom in).

So, to listen for a pinch event, you could do this:

```
var img = document.querySelector('img.myImage');
img .addEventListener('gestureend', function(e) {
if (e.scale < 1.0) {
    //User is pinching fingers together
} else if (e.scale > 1.0) {
    // User is spreading fingers apart
}}, false);
```

ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/GestureEventClassReference/GestureEvent/GestureEvent.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instp/GestureEvent/scale